# How to access nested resources in JSON server

Tags: json, json-server

I am trying to use json-server for my application.
My json file goes like this:

```
{
  "Categories": [
    {

      "item": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "product_id": 1,
          "description": "Pizza1",
          "price": 12.99,
          "pickup": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "product_id": 2,
          "description": "Pizza2",
          "price": 8.99,
          "pickup": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "product_id": 3,
          "description": "Pizza3",
          "price": 36.99,
          "pickup": 0
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

So the `item` is inside `Categories`. Now I am trying to add an `item` to to JSON file and I am not able to do that.
I can successfully add a `Category` by doing:
`this._http.post('http://localhost:3000'+'/Categories',{JSON STRUCTURE})` but I cannot add things inside Category.
It is not something like attaching `/Categories/item` at end of `localhost:3000`

The [documentation's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#add-custom-routes) "custom routes" is really confusing me.

Comment: What "documentation" are you referring to? Where is your insert code and endpoint for adding an item?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#add-custom-routes

Comment: [Filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#filter) allows you to access nested properties. Try posting to `/Categories.item` instead of `/Categories/item`

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by the library. The way to get this working is to add a custom routes file to de server, where you will map (or redirect) requests made to `/rest/user/` to `/`.

`db.json`

```
 {
    "item": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "product_id": 1,
          "description": "Pizza1",
          "price": 12.99,
          "pickup": 0
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "product_id": 2,
          "description": "Pizza2",
          "price": 8.99,
          "pickup": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "product_id": 3,
          "description": "Pizza3",
          "price": 36.99,
          "pickup": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

`routes.json`

```
{
  "/Categories/*": "/$1"
}
```

and then run it using `json-server db.json --routes routes.json`

Hope it helps!